# Include a TeX file in a section

Tags: include

I want to include a document in one of my section. For example,

```
\section{Introduction}
We are blablabla.....

\section{Our Previous Document: Document 1}
\include{Document1.tex}
```

Unfortunately, when I tried to build it, I couldn't see the document (document1) in my section. Can anyone help me?

Comment: if it didn't work there was presumably an error, but as you neither showed the error nor showed the file that was included impossible to say. You do however want `\input` not `\include` otherwise you will have a page break after the section heading

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I didn't show the error because there isn't any.

Comment: So you see a section for "Introduction", a section for "Our Previous Document...", and then whatever is immediately after your failing include command, with nothing in between it and the "Our Previous Document..." header?

Comment: @lukehollup that's unlikely. Does your `Document1.tex` by any chance include a preamble?

Comment: @lukehollup it is really hard to make tex drop text without showing an error, but if you do not show the input nor log file (even an error free log) then how can anyone help?

Comment: unless you have used `\includeonly` (but once you change the `\include` to `\input` then even `\includeonly` would not be a problem.

Comment: I think the issue is the documents collapse with each other. I noticed that the table of content is overlapping after I put \include{}

Comment: only you can see the document if you just give vague descriptions without showing the errors and without showing any code that anyone can debug, then no one can help. Make a small complete document that shows the problem, then post that as an example, then probably someone will debug it and tell you how to fix it within minutes.

Comment: @lukehollup Overlapping with what? I thought you said the document didn't appear at all? Since `\include` starts a new page, hard to see how it could overlap.

Comment: As stated `\include` is the wrong command here, use `\input`. Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include for more information.